# How can I make live changes to Javascript in chrome webdeveloper tool?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to figure out how I can make a change to javascript and then reload the page with the new javascript changes in the same way you can change CSS and html on the fly. I understand that the javascript will need to actually reload the page, but the problem is once you reload it redownloads the original javascript on the server.

So how can I modify the javascript on the fly so that I can test the design with the new javascript changes without having to upload it to the server?

Comment: Use a local development server.

Comment: I am really only looking to find out how to make changes javascript with chrome dev tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you're wanting to use the [LiveEdit feature in Chrome](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging#liveedit)? Using it is as simple as opening the Developer Tools, go to the Sources panel, and use the `Ctrl/Cmd + Shift + O` to find the script you want to edit. Then click the pause button to pause debugging, modify the script as needed, then `Ctrl/Cmd + S` to save your modifications, and finally click the pause/resume button to resume execution.

Comment: That is what I am looking for. Although what if I am trying to change javascript that runs on page load?

Comment: Is there a way to automatically break before the script has been executed? So I can make my changes?

Comment: @user1632018 You could add a [`debugger` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger) at the very top of the JavaScript file.

Comment: @user1632018 You can also add breakpoints to your script by clicking on the line number to the left (in the Sources panel) and reloading the page. Since this is what you're looking for, feel free to accept it as the answer.

Comment: The issue here is that when I reload the page, chrome redownloads the javascript files overwriting the changes I made. It seems I can only make changes to scripts that run after the page has loaded. Can you confirm this method works? If so then it must be a caching issue on my end.